# Is it possible to create new checkbox while updating mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, i have checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='fruit' value='apple'> Apple
<input type='checkbox' name='fruit' value='orange'> Orange
```

These checkbox values are in separate MySQL table.

How to create new checkbox when I add new value to MySQL table?

f.e. Updating table with value 'banana' creates checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='fruit' value='banana'> Banana
```

Thank you.

Comment: you tagged the question with `php`, `javascript` and `mysql` yet only show `HTML` which isnt tagged !!! what is your actual question ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Are you saying you want your page to be generated using values from the database table, or that where your page is already displayed in a browser it should automatically refresh when a new value is added to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible you  need to query in to database and display checkboxes using PHP on form according to query results.